# Frame not set to size defined Java

Tags: java, swing

I am learning on how to make an applet. I have a frame which contains the applet. Within the applet, there are 4 different panels: One main panel (with BorderLayout) and 3 sub-panels within the main one()-one to the North, one to the South and one to Center). 
Whenever I launch the applet, the main frame size is very small. I tried to change it using setSize() but it doesnt work. I then tried using setPreferedSize() and pack() from other posts, but it doesn't work for me. 
Here is my code:

```
        BounceBallApp applet = new BounceBallApp();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("BounceBallApp");

        frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Is it that I should also set the size for the applet and for each panel?

Comment: 1) *"I am learning on how to make an applet. I have a frame which contains the applet."*  Then make a panel that is put into either frame or applet, rather than an applet that is put into a frame.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Oh, well I have been following one chapter "Applets" in a book and in all the examples, the applet is contained within a frame. Or maybe I am understanding something wrong. Excerpt: "When the applet is run standalone, the main method is invoked to create a frame to hold the applet".

Comment: *"Oh, well I have been following one chapter "Applets" in a book and in all the examples, the applet is contained within a frame"*  That book is not good educational material.  It is not worth the paper it is written on.  Use it for something useful like a door-stop, or kindling.

Comment: @user1719821 As Andrew has stated, the correct way to mix Applets and Frames is through the use a common container, like `JPanel` which can be added to either as needed.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone for the tips. I am going to look more into that!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's your problem...

```
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.pack(); <-- This is you're problem, or is it...
```

`pack` will you use the layout managers preferred size to "pack" the frame so you don't have to guess...

From the Java Docs...

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are
>   automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the
>   minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize
>   method.
>
> If the window and/or its owner are not displayable yet, both of them
>   are made displayable before calculating the preferred size. The Window
>   is validated after its size is being calculated.

Also...I can't begin to wounder why you want to mix two top level containers in this way, but I'd really encourage you not to...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Component#setMinimumSize(...)` this won't allow for any layout manager, to violate this minimum size.

Comment: Oh I'm sure there are some that will ;)